# Creating custom posts directly from the ACF form

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to mimic the 'Locations' functionality of Events Manager plugin where the user, when adding new events, can search for existing locations and if not found - create one straight from the form.

Is there an ACF way of approaching this? I was thinking of using the `acf_form` functionality but I'm not sure how to plug it into a form.

Wordpress 4.7.3, ACF Pro 5.5.11

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do that by using the 'Clone' field and cloning field groups for the custom post type I wanted to create. Then I hooked to `acf/save_post` action and using `wp_insert_post()` and `update_field()` managed to create a new custom post from a different post's custom post.

This was used in replicating 'Events Manager' functionality. I had a custom post type 'Event' and 'Location'. When adding a new 'Event' I could select from the existing locations or (and that's what I used the new functionality) add a new location.

I hope that helps someone else who's working on similar things :)